# Manifest File not working on ipad device when working offline

Tags: javascript, html

my web page is not working offline on ipad device below is the url of my web

http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html manifest=brd.manifest>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
        <meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=black />
        <meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=yes />
        <link rel=apple-touch-icon href=brd_icon.png />
        <title>BRD</title>
        <link type="text/css" href=newstyle_tester.css rel=stylesheet />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.queryloader2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest file is being served with a mime type of text/plain. That should be text/cache-manifest otherwise mist browsers just ignore it.

Comment: That completely depends on the web server you are using. Usually you add a mapping per extension. In IIS you use the `<staticContent>` in the config in Apache you use `AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest`

Comment: I have done like the second AddType text/cache-manifest.manifet

Comment: how to creat a htaccess file on server

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+a+htaccess+file+on+apache)

Comment: i know creating htacessfile on sever i have added correct mime type but i don't get why this is not working